# Resolving dependencies using npm while installing Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-4

While installing Bootstrap 4 using `npm` it show me these errors:

```
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0-beta requires a peer of jquery@>=3.0.0 but none was installed. 
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0-beta requires a peer of popper.js@^1.11.0 but none was installed.
```

I'm using Git Bash, I also tried to install jQuery individually but it couldn't be installed.
Can someone help me to fix these issues? Manu thanks

Comment: No, I recant my previous statement.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll need to install those dependencies and save them to you `package.json`

`npm install jquery@3.0.0 --save
npm install popper.js@1.11.0 --save`

[The docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

just try this as well:

npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap